# Question about separating service into microservices

Tags: java, architecture, admin

Currently we have core service that contains functionality for User and Admin user.
We want to separate user and admin functionality into different microservices. Therefore, decrease load on them and separate codebase(although some code will repeat).
These microservices will use the same DB.

What do you think, is it a good idea to separate the microservices?
What are prods and cons? Are there any best practises for this?

Answer (score 3):

If two micro services share the same database they have lots of dependencies regarding database schema, database structure, availability, deployment etc. Thus they do not achieve one of the core requirement of a micro service, namely that each micro service is truly independent. So they are not two micro services but a single complex one.

The shared/repeated code is a further indication that splitting the micro services into two isn't the best idea.

I'm further surprised that you expect benefits regarding the load by splitting it into a user and an admin service. Typically, admin related load is very small compared to user related load. Thus I would expect that 99% of today's load would still go to the user service after the split. If so, you wouldn't achieve the initial goal.

Overall, I think it's a bad idea. I don't see any advantage at all. If excessive load is the main problem, solve it by running multiple instance of the current micro service.